# NullInjectorError when using ngTemplate to project filter into table

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, primeng

I have a component that has a primeng table and inside a table row I have an ng-container that is used to project a p-columnFilter into the table from the outside. Whenever pass the filter into the template I get a NullInjector error, because the component from the outside is in another module, but still would import the primengmodules.

> ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(RootModule)[Table -> Table ->
> Table -> Table]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for Table!
> at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:11172:27)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11339:33)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11339:33)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11339:33)
> at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21902:33)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11339:33)
> at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21902:33)
> at Object.get (core.mjs:21579:35)
> at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3374:39)
> at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3486:12)

root.component.html:
[image]

view-edtior.component.html:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I already got a solution by injecting Table, TableService in the providers section of the module in which the root.component lives.
[image]

I figured out that p-columnfilter does not work outside of a table if the providers are not defined and since ng-template is just providing the content but actually is creating it outside of the table the providers must be specified.

Comment: Please don't add code as images